# function to merge multiple tables together

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and have about two weeks under my belt.

I am attempting to merge 12 months of data (each table representing a month) into 1 year worth of data in a single table. the column's names are common across all 12 tables.

I struggle to find the correct function to merge these 12 tables simultaneously (potentially using a list()) while keeping the same columns.

To start, this is all the code I have available so far:

```
nov_2021 <- read_csv("202111-divvy-tripdata.csv")
dec_2021 <- read_csv("202112-divvy-tripdata.csv")
jan_2022 <- read_csv("202201-divvy-tripdata.csv")
feb_2022 <- read_csv("202202-divvy-tripdata.csv")
mar_2022 <- read_csv("202203-divvy-tripdata.csv")
apr_2022 <- read_csv("202204-divvy-tripdata.csv")
may_2022 <- read_csv("202205-divvy-tripdata.csv")
jun_2022 <- read_csv("202206-divvy-tripdata.csv")
jul_2022 <- read_csv("202207-divvy-tripdata.csv")
aug_2022 <- read_csv("202208-divvy-tripdata.csv")
sep_2022 <- read_csv("202209-divvy-publictripdata.csv")
```

My first thought was to use joins, but then I realized that this was to find common rows in the tables as opposed to columns.

(also, if anyone can shed light on how to read multiple csv files at once rather than individually inputting 12, i would appreciate the insight)

Answer (score 1):

```
files <- c("202111-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202112-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202201-divvy-tripdata.csv", 
"202202-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202203-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202204-divvy-tripdata.csv", 
"202205-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202206-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202207-divvy-tripdata.csv", 
"202208-divvy-tripdata.csv", "202209-divvy-publictripdata.csv"
)

list2DF(lapply(files, read.csv))
```